# [VBA Excel]Check which cell is empty then fill in

Tags: vba, excel

Guys I have a problem :(

I want excel to find the closest empty cell in A then write a number in that cell.
Then go one to the right -> and type another number

Anybody help me :D?

Comment: Hi, Please share the Code you worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

By *closest*, I mean *closest to* **A1**:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim r As Range
   On Error GoTo bottom
   Set r = Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)(1)
   r.Value = "a number"
   r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "another number"
   Exit Sub
bottom:
   Set r = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
   r.Value = "a number"
   r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "another number"
   On Error Resume Next
End Sub
```